# Delete/Update record of model is not working in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have made simple CRUD program [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/14/).

But on click of delete (here i am trying to delete first record of model) it is not deleting any record,it is throwing error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {..} has no method 'deleteRecord'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue i am struggling on this issue from last 2 days?
I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/14/).

I have edited my fiddle to add functionality of create record [(here)](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/19/)
It is adding blank records in table.
Can anyone tell me how to add/create record in this case?

```
    savecontact: function(){
    App.Person.createRecord({   
          fname: this.get('firstName'),
          lname: this.get('lastName'),
          contactype: 1
        });
        this.get('store').commit(); 
},
```

Comment: please see my edited jsbin, it is now working for delete and update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this line is what changed:

```
this.get('store').deleteRecord(App.Person.find(1));
```

You where calling `deleteRecord` on a class definition `App.Person` which of course throws an error.

See working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/16/) here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,it is working now for delete.Can you help me to solve update issue of same fiddle.

Comment: Actually i am new to this community just now i come to know how to accept answer. I will do this now onward.I have accepted this answer

Comment: I have updated last fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GYbeT/19/ to add create functionality but it is adding blank records.Can you show me why it is adding blank records?